# Can't set submit button

Tags: forms, symfony

I created a form with a submit button type in it. But it doesn't work.

Here is the form :

```
class DisputedType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        //->add('points')
        ->add('position')
        ->add('joueur', EntityType::class, [
            // looks for choices from this entity
            'class' => Joueur::class,

            // uses the User.username property as the visible option string
            'choice_label' => 'prenom',
            'expanded' => 'true',
            'multiple' => 'true'
        ])
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Suivant']);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Disputed::class,
    ]);
}
}
```

Then the twig view :

```
<h1>Sélectionnez les joueurs</h1>

{{ form(form) }}
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_row(form.save)}}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

But it gives me this error :

> Neither the property "save" nor one of the methods "save()", "getsave()"/"issave()"/"hassave()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".

I don't know why I get this error message. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Can you remove 
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_row(form.save)}}
{{ form_end(form) }} and left  {{ form(form) }} only and try again?

Comment: @AythaNzt the form show up but without the submit button

Comment: What happen with this? Remove the others and use this only {{ form_start(form) }} {{ form_widget(form) }} {{ form_end(form) }}

Comment: Paste your controller too please

Comment: Ow, nevermind, I saw what I was doing wrong. I wasn't using the correct form... Thank you anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

Above code itself rendered all fields.
So you have use either this line or below code

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_row(form.save)}}
{{ form_end(form)}}
```